# SqlCeCommand exception

Tags: c#, sql

I have this code:

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
connection.Open();
connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Settings (id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, host nvarchar(50), port int, rk_host nvarchar(50), rk_port int, stationcode int, guesttypecode int)";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Settings ([host], [port], [rk_host], [rk_port], [stationcode], [guesttypecode]) VALUES ('" + Settings.host + "', '" + Settings.rk_host + "', '" + Settings.rk_port + "', '" + Settings.port + "', '" + Settings.stationcode + "', '" + Settings.guesttypecode + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

And on the second `ExecuteNonQuery` I have an exception: `"Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]"`

Can anybody help me?

Comment: First up - stop putting values into your SQL. Use paramerized SQL commands instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Int type columns you should remove single quote from query

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Settings ([host], [port], [rk_host], [rk_port], [stationcode], [guesttypecode]) VALUES ('" + Settings.host + "', '" + Settings.rk_host + "', " + Settings.rk_port + ", '" + Settings.port + "', " + Settings.stationcode + ", " + Settings.guesttypecode + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is never write your queries like this because that would cause [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Second, your are reading from your settings and insert them into your table without considering their types. you need to to type conversion (e.g. `int.Parse(Settings.port)`